# Set icon onPress based on the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to set the onPress to call a `action` to dispatch of an Icon, depending on a state in Redux.

```
   <MaterialIcons
      name="arrow-upward" size={30} style={mystyles1.myIcon}
      onPress =  this.props.style.name === 'styleNormal' ? 
          {() => this.props.changeStyleNew('styleNew')} : 
          {()=>this.props.changeStyleNormal('styleNormal')}
    >
    </MaterialIcons>
```

So if the `this.props.style.name === 'styleNormal'` the first function (`changeStyleNew`) should be passed, if not the second (`changeStyleNormal`). I'm not able to achieve this. I'm getting an error:

```
TransformError C:/.../ExtComp02.js: 
JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (94:19)
```

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the expression inside curly brackets `{}` like this

```
<MaterialIcons
      name="arrow-upward" size={30} style={mystyles1.myIcon}
      onPress = {
          this.props.style.name === 'styleNormal' ? 
          () => this.props.changeStyleNew('styleNew') : 
          ()=>this.props.changeStyleNormal('styleNormal')
      }
    >
</MaterialIcons>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a 3rd function and use a if statement.

```
<MaterialIcons
    name="arrow-upward" size={30} style={mystyles1.myIcon}
    onPress={ () => {
     if (this.props.style.name === 'styleNormal') this.props.changeStyleNew('styleNew');
     else this.props.changeStyleNormal('styleNormal');
    }}
>
</MaterialIcons>
```